# Triggering an event to fire on a form when an event on a frame occurs

Tags: delphi

I have a form that Contains a List box. The form is also parent to a frame which contains a scrollbox on which panels are drawn. When the user selects x number of items from the listbox and clicks on a panel the panels subdivide into x number smaller panels (ex. if the user selects 3 items from the list box and then clicks on a single panel on the frame it will divide itself into 3 smaller panels).

We set a limit for each panel before hand as to how many items can be selected for the panels (ex. a user sets the limit to 2 then selects 3 items and tries to click on a panel, a warning displays saying you can't do that) When the warning displays I want to return the items to the list box so the user has them to select from (as the action couldn't be completed as it wasn't allowed).

I wrote this code to accomplish what I want, the problem is those objects are not available to me at the time of the event (I tried adding the parent form to the Implementation uses clause and calling it with fmSeatingAssignments.UndoSelection, but quickly found out that the instance of the objects I need are out of scope).

```
procedure TfmSeatAssignments.UndoSelection;
Var
 I: Integer;
begin
 for I := 0 to FVehicleLayout.SelStudents.Count - 1 do
 begin
  ListBox1.Items.Add(FVehicleLayout.SelStudents[I]);
 end;
 For I := 0 to ListBox1.Count - 1 do
 begin
  ListBox1.Selected[I] := False;
 end;
 FVehicleLayout.SelStudents.Clear;
end;
```

FVehicleLayout is the frame and houses a Stringlist that takes in the selected items (which are then removed from the list box). I want to call the aforementioned code after the dialog in the following code closes, which is on the frame:

```
procedure TFrameVehicleLayout.ClickEvent(Sender: TObject);
var
 I,Row,Side: Integer;
begin
TooManyOstrichs := False;
If SelStudents.Count > 0 then
begin
 Side := -1;
 For I:=0 to High(Bus.BusSide) do
 begin
 If Bus.BusSide[I].LookupPanel(TPanel(Sender), Row) Then
 begin
  Side := I;
  break;
 end;
end;
If Side = 0 then
begin
 If SelStudents.Count > VehicleLayout.fDSSeats then
 begin
  vsiMessageDlg('The number of selected students exceeds the amount allowed ' +
               'per row for this bus side. Please try again.',
              mtWarning, [mbok], mbok, Self.Handle);

  //Call fmSeatAssignments.UndoSelection
  exit;
 end;
end;
if side <> -1 then
begin
  TRow(Bus.BusSide[Side].Rows[Row]).Occupants.Assign(SelStudents);
  TRow(Bus.BusSide[Side].Rows[Row]).FreePanels;
  TRow(Bus.BusSide[Side].Rows[Row]).BuildPanelArray;
  ShowLayout;
  SelStudents.Clear;
 end;
end;
end;
```

Any help on how to get those items in the SelStudents stringlist back into the listbox would be much appreciated. If any of this is confusing or not clear enough let me know and I will make a demo program and post full code. Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: The only external reference you need is the listbox. Declare a field on the frame and set it to the form's listbox when you create the frame, of course move the UndeSelection method to the frame. If you don't like this, get the parent form of the frame and iterate controls until you find a list box. Possibly other solutions as well..

Comment: I was able to use your suggestion to get this to work. Please post as an answer so I can give you credit. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome! I tried to make out an answer of that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only external reference you need is the listbox. You can declare a field on the frame and set it to the form's listbox when you create the frame, of course you need to move the `UndoSelection` method to the frame with this solution.

Alternatively, if you don't want to move the method, you can declare and publish an event on the frame, and assign it a procedure of the parent form on creation time. Might look something like this:

```
type
  TFrameVehicleLayout = class(TFrame)
  private
    FOnUndoSelection: TNotifyEvent;
  public
    property OnUndoSelection: TNotifyEvent read FOnUndoSelection write FOnUndoSelection;
  end;

procedure TFrameVehicleLayout.ClickEvent(Sender: TObject);
..
begin
  ..
  if Assigned(OnUndoSelection) then
    OnUndoSelection(Self);
  ..
```

assigning the property at the form:

```
type
  TfmSeatAssignments = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    procedure OnFrameUndoSelection(Sender: TObject);
  public
    ..


var
  F: TFrameVehicleLayout;
begin
  F := TFrameVehicleLayout.Create(Self);
  F.OnUndoSelection := OnFrameUndoSelection;
  ..
```

You can also get the parent form of the frame (`GetParentForm¯) and iterate controls until you find a list box. Or maybe post a user message to the form that it understands. There may be other solutions as well.

Comment: Sertac, Thank you so much for your help. All of your suggestions were extremely useful. This cleared up a lot of the questions I had. I appreciate you taking the time to share your knowledge with me.